# Jquery dynamic accordion: panel heading colour only with newly added panel?

Tags: jquery, html, styles, selector, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a  dynamic jquery accordion. I have 2 fields at the top. After both the fields are filled and the user presses the "add question button", a new panel is added at the top with a blue heading. As I keep adding questions, more and more panels are prepended and their headings are also in blue. I have added the code for the blue headings in my jquery section where I am adding my panels.

I also have a submit button, which refreshes the page and returns the page back to default (so all previous panels are lost).

Here is the output: https://jsfiddle.net/5gLb0cqx/

My Question is this: I am trying to make it so that *only* the newly added panel has a blue heading.

my code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  var counter = 2;

  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        });

    function edit(){
    var text = $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
    var sql = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();
    $("#input").val(text);
    $("#sql_code").val(sql);
    }
    $(":button").click(edit);

    $("#addAccordion").click( function() {
        var inputVal = $("#input").val();
        var sqlVal = $("textarea#sql_code").val();
        if (!sqlVal || !inputVal){
            return;
        }
        var newDiv = '<div><h3 style = "background:lightblue;">Question '+ counter +'</h3></div>';
        var content = '<div class = "new_panel"><label>'+inputVal+'</label><br><br><label for="in" name="question">Edit Question:</label> <input type="text" name = "question" value ="'+inputVal+'" /><br><br>'
        + ' <label name="SQL">Edit SQL code here:</label><textarea name = "code">'+sqlVal+'</textarea>' +
        '<br><br> <input type = "button" value = "Edit" ></input></div>';
        $("#accordion").prepend(newDiv +content) ;
        $("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
        counter++;
        $(":button").click(edit);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<form id="myform">
    <label>Enter Question:</label>
    <input id="input" type="text" name = "questions"/>
    <br><br>
    <label>Enter SQL code here:</label>
    <textarea id="sql_code" name = "SQL_code"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input id = "submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type = "button" id ="addAccordion" value = "Add Question" ></input>
</form>
</center>

<div id = "accordion">
    <h3> Question 1 </h3>
    <div>
        <form>
            Have you ever been tested for an STI?
            <br><br>
            <label for="in" name="question1">Edit Question:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
            <br><br>
            <label for="sql" name="SQL">Edit SQL code here:</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type = "button" value = "Edit" ></input>
            </form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to do this with my current code.

I was thinking of somehow looping through the accordion panels and finding the newest panel added, although I have no idea how to do this.

Can anyone can point me in the right direction or have any suggestions as to how to tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5gLb0cqx/3/)

Provided you have h3 only in the heading of each panel, just add one line in jQuery

```
$("#accordion").find("h3").not(":first").css({"background":"none"})
```

after prepending a newly panel, OR

```
$("#accordion").find("h3").css({"background":"none"})
```

before prepending.

Answer (score 0):

change some jquery

```
var newDiv = '<div style="background:lightblue;"><h3 style="margin:2px 0 0;">Question '+ counter +'</h3></div>';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gLb0cqx/2/